# Präteritum oder Perfekt?

Tags: perfect-tense, preterite

Ich habe eine Frage bezüglich des Präteritums, nämlich habe ich in einer Serie gesehen: Auf dem Nachhauseweg sah ich einen Panzer. Das war in einem Gespräch und das klingt mir komisch, da das doch relevant ist und beschreibt etwas, was vor einem Moment geschah. Also sollte es nicht dort eher: habe ich gesehen" stehen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Perfekt gehört zum Präsens. Es bezeichnet ein Geschehen, das zur Zeit des Präsens abgeschlossen ist (auf Grammatisch: perfektiver Aspekt).

Das Präteritum ist hingegen die Zeitstufe der Vergangenheit. Es bezeichnet also ein Geschehen, das nicht zur Zeit des Präsens gehört, sondern zu einer früheren Zeit. Üblicherweise wird es als Erzählform verwendet.

Viele von uns mit deutscher Muttersprache haben jedoch nur eine sehr schlechte Intuition für die Unterscheidung der beiden Formen, denn in einem grossen Teil des deutschen Sprachraums wird nur das Perfekt verwendet. So kommt es dann zur Hyperkorrektur wie in diesem Fall.

Comment: Also ist Hyperkorrektur eig falsch?

Comment: @Damian: Es kann richtig sein, aber nicht aus den von mach genannten Gründen, sondern aus den von Janka genannten.

Answer (score 1):

Präteritum oder Perfekt entscheidet sich im Deutschen nicht anhand des zeitlichen Bezugs, sondern anhand der Sprachebene und des Dialekts.

Im Schriftlichen wird das Präteritum verwendet, im Mündlichen das Perfekt. Je weiter nördlich man kommt, bei desto mehr Verben wird auch im Mündlichen das Präteritum verwendet.

Comment: Aber würdest du hier Präteritum nutzen, wenn du selbst diesen Satz schreiben müsstest?

Comment: In einer Geschichte oder im Schriftverkehr in jedem Fall. Beim Sprechen nicht. Aber vielleicht hast du das ja in Lüneburg gehört, und das liegt nördlicher.

Comment: Gegenbeispiel, das die Sache verdeutlicht: «Ich sah einen Panzer. Wir müssen unverzüglich den Stab informieren.» Hier ist das Präteritum deplaziert, und zwar insbesondere im Norden und in guter geschriebener Sprache, wo Präteritum und Perfekt voneinander unterschieden werden. Mit korrektem zeitlichen Bezug müsste es nämlich heissen: «Ich habe einen Panzer gesehen. Wir müssen unverzüglich den Stab informieren.»

Comment: Das ist eine Wiedergabe des Mündlichen im Schriftlichen, sonst wäre bereits das Präsens falsch.

Comment: *Es gab im Laden keine Kartoffeln, also gab's zum Mittag Nudeln.* Völlig ok. Genauso wie zweimal Perfekt, oder Präteritum, Perfekt. Oder Perfekt, Präteritum. Völlig egal, alles ok.